# Creating a new javascript object in QML

Tags: javascript, qml

I'm trying to create a new javascript object in QML.

In javascript I would simply:

```
var newObject = new Object();
```

but this is flagged as an error by QtCreator

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you add some more code? Could you cite the exact error message? I get a feeling that you mixed QML and JS code. Please have in mind that QML contains QML code which is not JS. You can embed JS in QML easily but not just by putting JS anywhere in QML file. [Have a look at examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-expressions.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `new`. You can just create an empty JS Object like this in a script part (e.g. signal handler, function etc.)

```
var newObject = {} // In a script.
```

or as a property:

```
property var someObject: ({}) // You need to wrap it in paranthesis
```

If you insist on the `new`-keyword

```
var someOtherObject = new Object // In a script
```

seems to be working, too.

Comment: Thanks, moved code to a js include and all object creation worked fine!